# How do I get ng-init to work with mutiple functions in a controller?

Tags: angularjs, function, controller

My html:

```
<div ng-app="APSApp" class="container">
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Terms" />
    <br />
    <div ng-controller="APSCtl" >
        <table class="table">
            <tr ng-repeat="r in searchTerms" ng-init="searchTerms=getSearchTerms()" >
                <td>{{r.DisplayText}} <input type="text" ng-model="r.SearchInput"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    const moduleId = '@Dnn.ModuleContext.ModuleId';
    const tabId = '@Dnn.ModuleContext.TabId';
</script>
<script src="/DesktopModules/RazorCart/Core/Content/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="/DesktopModules/MVC/AdvancedProductSearchMVC/Scripts/AdvancedProductSearch.js"></script>
```

My angular setup:

```
var aps = angular.module("APSApp", []);
aps.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(data) {
        return data !== undefined ? $.param(data) : null;
    };
});

aps.factory('SearchTerms', 
    function($http) {
        return {
            getSearchTerms: function(onSuccess, onFailure) {
                const rvtoken = $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();
                $http({
                    method: "post",
                    url: "/DesktopModules/MVC/AdvancedProductSearchMVC/AdvancedProductSearch/GetAPS",
                    headers: {
                        "ModuleId": moduleId,
                        "TabId": tabId,
                        "RequestVerificationToken": rvtoken
                    }
                }).success(onSuccess).error(onFailure);
            }
        };
    });


aps.controller('APSCtl',
    function(SearchTerms, $scope) {
        function getSearchTerms() {
            $scope.searchTerms = [];
            successFunction = function(data) {
                $scope.searchTerms = data;
                console.log($scope.searchTerms);
            };

            failureFunction = function(data) {
                console.log('Error' + data);
            };
            SearchTerms.getSearchTerms(successFunction, failureFunction);
        }

        function doSomethingElse($scope) {}

    });
```

I'm trying to create a single controller with multiple functions. This works if my angular controller looks like this (and I don't use ng-init):

```
aps.controller('APSCtl',
    function(SearchTerms, $scope) {
            $scope.searchTerms = [];
            successFunction = function(data) {
                $scope.searchTerms = data;
                console.log($scope.searchTerms);
            };

            failureFunction = function(data) {
                console.log('Error' + data);
            };
            SearchTerms.getSearchTerms(successFunction, failureFunction);
    });
```

I was just trying to keep related functions in a single controller. What am I doing wrong? Do I actually have to set up a different controller for each function?

Comment: Your `getSearchTerms` function is not assigned to the `$scope` that's probably the reason it never gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to assign the value in the template, you can just call the function,

```
 <table class="table" ng-init="getSearchTerms()>
            <tr ng-repeat="r in searchTerms" >
                <td>{{r.DisplayText}} <input type="text" ng-model="r.SearchInput"></td>
            </tr>
 </table>
```

you should have a function named getSearchTerms() in your controller to get it called,

```
aps.controller('APSCtl',
    function(SearchTerms, $scope) {
         $scope.getSearchTerms() {
            $scope.searchTerms = [];
            successFunction = function(data) {
                $scope.searchTerms = data;
                console.log($scope.searchTerms);
            };

            failureFunction = function(data) {
                console.log('Error' + data);
            };

            SearchTerms.getSearchTerms(successFunction, failureFunction);
        }

        function doSomethingElse($scope) {}

    });
```

Comment: I tried that. Same issue. The controller never gets called.

Comment: you need to have a function inside the controller as   "$scope.getSearchTerms()"

Comment: Sorry. I'm not sure what you mean. I should rename my getSearchTerms() to $scopre.getSearchTerms()?

Comment: Or $scope.getSearchTerms= function(){